# Proposition on Probability

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

**Proposition** : $P(E \cup F) = P(E) + P(F) - P(EF)$
I have the following laws and axioms available to me:

#### Laws from Set Theory

**Commumutative Laws**: $E \cup F = F \cup E$; $EF=FE$
**Associative Laws**: $(E \cup F) \cup G = E\cup(F \cup G)$; $(EF)G = E(FG)$
**Distributive Laws**: $(E \cup F)G=EG\cup FG$; $EF \cup G = (E \cup G)(F \cup G)$

#### DeMorgan's Laws

$(E \cup F)^c = E^cF^c$
$(EF)^c = E^c \cup F^c$

#### Axioms of Probability

**Axiom 1**: $0 \leq P(E) \leq 1$
**Axiom 2**: $P(S) = 1$
**Axiom 3**: $P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}E_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(E_i) $ For $E_i$ mutually exclusive

#### My attempt

I tried to use **Axiom 3** by constructing mutually exclusive sets: Sets $(E-F), EF, (F-E)$ are mutually exclusive and we can write
$$
P(E \cup F) = P(E-F)+P(EF)+P(F-E)
$$
However, this requires another proposition that $P(X-Y) = P(X) - P(XY)$. The proof requires a Venn diagram. The first proposition has also been proved using a Venn diagram in the book. I am wondering if the proposition can be proved using the laws and axioms alone.

Comment: Well, $X = X \cup (Y - Y) = XY \cup (X - Y),$ right? And $XY \cap (X - Y) = X \cap (Y - Y) = \emptyset.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan didn't understand why $X \cup (Y-Y) = XY \cup (X-Y)$, which law are you using here?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't write it out before commenting and it seems I confused myself somehow: what I should've done was $X = X \cap S = X \cap (Y \cup Y^c) = (X \cap Y) \cup (X \cap Y^c) = XY \cup (X - Y).$ It's just using the distributive property

Comment: @StephenDonovan thank you, and it is easy to show that $XY \cap (X-Y) = \phi$ from set theory (hopefully this translates nicely to probability). Then we use the third axiom to prove the proposition. This is what I understood. If you want you can write the answer and I will accept it.